# Flask output not showing

Tags: xgboost, hyperparameter-tuning, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to deploy a `XGBClassifier` model using `flask`. After giving the values to the relevant fields on the webpage, the output is not being displayed. Below is my code:

```
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(data1, y, test_size = 0.2, 
random_state=69)

# IMPUTING NAN VALUES
train_x['JobType'].fillna(train_x['JobType'].value_counts().index[0], inplace = True) 
train_x['occupation'].fillna(train_x['occupation'].value_counts().index[0], inplace = True)

test_x['JobType'].fillna(train_x['JobType'].value_counts().index[0], inplace = True)
test_x['occupation'].fillna(train_x['occupation'].value_counts().index[0], inplace = True)

# SEPARATING CATEGORICAL VARIABLES
train_x_cat = train_x.select_dtypes(include = 'object')
train_x_num = train_x.select_dtypes(include = 'number')

test_x_cat = test_x.select_dtypes(include = 'object')
test_x_num = test_x.select_dtypes(include = 'number')

#ONE HOT ENCODING THE CATEGORICAL VARIABLES AND THEN CONCAT THEM TO NUMERICAL VARIABLES
ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse = False)
train_x_encoded = pd.DataFrame(ohe.fit_transform(train_x_cat))
train_x_encoded.columns = ohe.get_feature_names(train_x_cat.columns)

train_x_encoded = train_x_encoded.reset_index(drop = True)
train_x_num = train_x_num.reset_index(drop = True)
train_x1 = pd.concat([train_x_num, train_x_encoded], axis = 1)


test_x_encoded = pd.DataFrame(ohe.transform(test_x_cat))
test_x_encoded.columns = ohe.get_feature_names(test_x_cat.columns)

test_x_encoded = test_x_encoded.reset_index(drop = True)
test_x_num = test_x_num.reset_index(drop = True)
test_x1 = pd.concat([test_x_num, test_x_encoded], axis = 1)

#XGBC MODEL
model = XGBClassifier(random_state = 69)

#Hyperparameter tuning
def objective(trial):
    learning_rate = trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.001, 0.01)
    n_estimators = trial.suggest_int('n_estimators', 10, 500)
    sub_sample = trial.suggest_float('sub_sample', 0.0, 1.0)
    max_depth = trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 1, 20)

    params = {'max_depth' : max_depth,
           'n_estimators' : n_estimators,
           'sub_sample' : sub_sample,
           'learning_rate' : learning_rate}

    model.set_params(**params)

    return np.mean(-1 * cross_val_score(model, train_x1, train_y,
                                    cv = 5, n_jobs = -1, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error'))

xgbc_study = optuna.create_study(direction = 'minimize')
xgbc_study.optimize(objective, n_trials = 10)

xgbc_study.best_params
optuna_rfc_mse = xgbc_study.best_value

model.set_params(**xgbc_study.best_params)
model.fit(train_x1, train_y)
```

This is my Flask (app.py) code:-

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'GET':
       return render_template('index.html')

    if request.method == "POST":
       AGE= request.form['age']
       JOBTYPE= request.form['JobType']
       EDUCATIONTYPE= request.form['EdType']
       MARITALSTATUS= request.form['maritalstatus']
       OCCUPATION= request.form['occupation']
       RELATIONSHIP= request.form['relationship']
       GENDER= request.form['gender']
       CAPITALGAIN= request.form['capitalgain']
       CAPITALLOSS= request.form['capitalloss']
       HOURSPERWEEK= request.form['hoursperweek']
    
       data = [[AGE, JOBTYPE, EDUCATIONTYPE, MARITALSTATUS, OCCUPATION, RELATIONSHIP, 
             GENDER, CAPITALGAIN, CAPITALLOSS, HOURSPERWEEK]]
    
       input_variables = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['age', 'JobType', 'EdType', 
                                                       'maritalstatus', 'occupation', 
                                                       'relationship', 'gender', 
                                                       'capitalgain', 'capitalloss', 
                                                       'hrsperweek'], 
                                                       dtype = 'float', index = ['input'])
    
       predictions = model.predict(input_variables)[0]
       print(predictions)
    
       return render_template('index.html', original_input = {'age':AGE, 'JobType':JOBTYPE, 
                                                              'EdType':EDUCATIONTYPE,
                                                           'maritalstatus':MARITALSTATUS, 
                                                           'occupation':OCCUPATION, 
                                                           'relationship':RELATIONSHIP, 
                                                           'gender':GENDER, 
                                                           'capitalgain':CAPITALGAIN,
                                                           'capitalloss':CAPITALLOSS, 
                                                           'hrsperweek':HOURSPERWEEK},
                                                            result = predictions)
```

My index.html code:-

```
<form action="{{ url_for('main') }}" method="POST">
    
    <div class="form_group">
    
        <legend>Input Variables</legend>
        
        <br>age<br>
        <input name="age" type="number" step="any" min="0" class="form 
        control" required>
        <br>
        <-- AND SO ON ALL THE INPUT ARE ADDED -->

        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        
    </div>
    
</form>
<br>

<div class="result" align="center">
    {% if result %} {% for variable, value in original_input.items() %}
    <b>{{ variable }}</b> : {{ value }} {% endfor %}
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1>Predicted Salary:</h1>
    <p style="font-size:50px">${{ result }}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

When I deploy it using Flask, give the values for each field on the webpage, it does not give me the predicted output. Instead it just refreshes with the output area blank as shown in red circle. I have to add an image because there's no other way to describe! [image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66491801/i-got-this-error-dataframe-dtypes-for-data-must-be-int-float-bool-or-categori

Comment: Yes but the solution given there don't work for me

Comment: Can you show the info table for input_variable dataframe by using input_variable.info() ?

Comment: `NameError: name 'input_variables' is not defined`. I tried running it inside as well as outside the if else loop

Comment: it is in you flask app. You need to submit some data and perhaps print it in the terminal.

Comment: Ok i did that and it is showing that there are object datatypes for JobType, EdType etc. But that is weird since I am using OHE to encode them. So why aren't they getting encoded?

Comment: You did that in your training and test step. You did no one hot encoding in your flask app. You have to do it here again to get correct predictions.

Comment: But I have done the same procedure for other models without encoding in the flask app and they work fine. Till now I have deployed 3 regression models without encoding them in the flaks app and  they work fine. This is my first classification problem that I am trying to deploy

Comment: I will need more details about your previous three models to infer anything. But you need to do one hot encode your input_variables dataframe in order to get result from xgboost.

Comment: Lemme try it and get back to you

Comment: I tried encoding input_variables but now I get following error `ValueError: feature_names mismatch`. I did OHE before `prediction = model.predict(input_variables)[0]`. I first separated cat and num columns, performed OHE on cat cols and then concatenated them. I also tried OHE the whole dataset without separating the cat and num cols but in both cases I got the same error

Comment: I also checked my encoded data frame and yes all features are float now

Comment: @SrJ Also encoding them in flask app doesn't make sense coz if I encode them then the column names and dimensions will change. Hence the model will expect 56 (due to increased dimensions coz of OHE) input from the user whereas the user is giving only 10 feature values as specified in the HTML code. Obviously there will be `feature_names mismatch`

Comment: You have to use the same encoding method for train and test purpose.

Comment: I have used the same method, heck even the same lines of code. Just changed the variable name that's all.

Comment: @SrJ Kindly check the updated question

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to fix your code.

One option is to write customs functions that contain the feature engineering code. Then call the functions before both training (`model.fit`) and prediction (`model.predict`).

Another option is use a framework that is designed to apply the appropriate transformations during training and prediction, an example is scikit-learn's [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html).

Comment: I have tried the above code with a Pipeline (which imputes and encodes) too but the result is same. Also I have used the same code for a regression model (which used decision tree regressor) and it worked fine

Comment: Kindly check the updated question

Answer (score 2):

*You have directly passed the request data into the model.*

We must do the required *pre-processing part i.e. OHE and Scaling etc*.

*If it worked in the past, it must be because the data would have been pure float for all features*.

 For doing pre-processing, *we must have the training phase encoders and statistics.*

Below is a toy example to show the should-be steps.

```py
# save the model/encoders to disk/DB after training
pickle.dump(model, open(model.sav, 'wb'))
pickle.dump(ohe, open('ohe.sav', 'wb'))

# Load model in the Flask runtime [ Only once ]
model = pickle.load(open('model.sav', 'rb')) # Loaded the Model
ohe_test = pickle.load(open('ohe.sav', 'rb')) # Loaded the OHE
# Get x_mean, x_median, x_std from Database/Files [Where it was saved ]

##Post method for Predict
@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict_():

    # Get request param
    jsonData = flask.request.get_json(force=True)
    data = pd.Series(jsonData)

    #Pre-processing
    data.fillna(x_median,inplace=True) # Fill NA
    data  = (data - x_mean)/x_std # Scale
    data  = ohe_test.transform(data) # OHE

    # Make prediction
    pred = model.predict([data])
  
    # Prepare output
    res = {'pred':pred}

    return flask.Response(response=json.dumps(res), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

**Note -**

- Handling of `unknown categories` is a separate task.
- Intent is not to guide on model serving. *There are dedicated Tools/Frameworks to build pipelines*.

Comment: I already tried encoding in the flask file but it does not work. Also I have used the same code implementation on a regression model which had categorical features too. There it worked fine.

Comment: Kindly check the updated question

Comment: Please check the backend logs. This can be the front-end response for the backend error

Comment: How can I do that? I am new to this

Comment: Add loggers/print in your Flask code.